# Object element returning undefined with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, addeventlistener

I am making a simple form which requests the user to input their project name and their name, along with some other info.

But each type of project has a different page, so to avoid copying and pasting the same getElementById and addEventListener functions in each page, I've made a module with those functions so every page handles it as needed. This is **one** of the pages:

```
// (imports)...

let project = {
  author: null,
  name: null,
  mission: {
    file: null,
    path: null,
  },
  sd: {
    code: null,
    path: null,
  },
  modloaderfolder: null,
};

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  project.mission = handleMission();
  project.sd = handleSD();
  project.modloaderfolder = handleModloader();
  project.name = handleName();
  project.author = handleAuthor();
// ...
```

The problem is that the objects' elements are returning `undefined` in the two following functions:

```
export function handleName() {
  const project = {};
  const txt_name = document.getElementById("name");
  txt_name.addEventListener("change", () => {
    project.name = txt_name.value;
  });
  return project.name;
}

export function handleAuthor() {
  const project = {};
  const txt_author = document.getElementById("author");
  txt_author.addEventListener("change", () => {
    project.author = txt_author.value;
  });

  return project.author;

}

// Returns undefined
```

Whats intriguing for me is that some other functions are working as intended, I can't find out why. These are the corretly working functions:

```
export function handleSD() {
  const project = { sd: {} };
  const input_sd = document.getElementById("sd");
  input_sd.addEventListener("change", () => {
    document.getElementById("sel-sd").innerHTML = "";
    Array.from(input_sd.files).forEach((file) => {
      document
        .getElementById("sel-sd")
        .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<option>${file.name}</option>`);
    });
    if (!input_sd.files[0]) return;
    const path = input_sd.files[0].path;
    project.sd.path = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("\\")) + "\\";
    project.sd.code = project.sd.path.substring(
      project.sd.path.lastIndexOf("\\") - 5,
      project.sd.path.length - 1
    );
  });

  return project.sd;
}

// This function correctly returns "sd: { path: ..., code: ...}"
```

What I noticed is that by returning an object, it returns and updates correctly for each change, but while returning an object's element, it aways returns `undefined`.

Comment: You'll note that the one that is 'working' returns an object while the two that aren't working return string properties *that don't exist at the time the function returns*. The returned object reference will update when the handler callback is called, but the undefined properties have no way to update. If you want to keep using this pattern you'll need to `return project;`  from the first two.

Answer (score 0):

which is empty and nothing will change it because copying a `primitive value` is `by value` but the object that holds the key of the string, and as soon as the `onchange` function is activated it changes the value of your key in the object and it automatically changes in your object too because it is copied `by Reference`.
You can read more about this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: Is there any way I could solve it without having to adapt the original `project` object structure?

Comment: @PedroToriality you need return `project` instead of `project.name` and `project.author`